# Почему выбираются не все элементы массива по запросу?

Tags: c#, linq

Задача сгенерировать случайным образом массив натуральных чисел и составить массив из полученного по следующему условию: взять все элементы массива, стоящие после минимального. Но почему-то он выбирает не все элементы.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int[] A;
        A = new int[Convert.ToInt32(textBox2A.Text)];
        GenerateArray(ref A, rnd);
        int min = Array.IndexOf(A, A.Min());
        var C = A.Where(item => Array.IndexOf(A, item) > min);
        string SA = String.Join
            (",", A.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
        string S = String.Join
            (",", C.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
        label2.Text = S;
        label2A.Text = SA;
    }
```

Например, ввел массив 18, 17, 8, 8, 17, 19, 18, 3, 17, 16.
А вывелось только 16, а должно 17 и 16.

Comment: 17 у вас встречается и до 3, поэтому он его не берет.

Comment: var C = A.Where(item => Array.LastIndexOf(A, item) > min);
Так выводится 17, но 3 раза

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka все равно спасибо, пригодится еще)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
var C = A.Where(item => Array.IndexOf(A, item) > min);
```

вставьте

```
var C = A.Skip(min+1);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!)